# using a tensor as index to an array in building the tensorflow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, indexing, numpy-ndarray, tensor

I'm trying to build a tensorflow graph for a network in python, in which i need the tensor (a scalar value) to be the index of a `np.array`
A sniped of the code is as follows:

```
def get_votes(input, classnum):
    in_shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
    votes = np.zeros([classnum])
    for i in range(0,in_shape[0]):
        print(input[i])
        votes[input[i]]=votes[input[i]]+1
```

Input is a 1D tensor.

The error I'm getting is this:

> votes[input[i]]=votes[input[i]]+1   File
> "C:\Anaconda3\envs\silvafilho\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py",
> line 736, in **array**
> " array.".format(self.name)) NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (strided_slice_1:0) to a numpy array.

I tried to use `tensor.eval(session=tf.Session())` but it needs a placeholder, which I don't have yet since I'm building the graph.

thanks a lot in advance if anyone knows a way to work around it.
I'm using `tensorflow_gpu 1.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using `tf.InteractiveSession()`, get the tensor value within `InteractiveSession()` and then do the operation as below.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input = tf.constant([5])
classnum = 10
def get_votes(input, classnum):
    in_shape = input.get_shape().as_list()
    votes = np.zeros([classnum])
    for i in range(0,in_shape[0]):
        sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
        input = input.eval()
        print(input[i])
        votes[input[i]]=votes[input[i]]+1
        sess.close()
    return votes
```

**Output:**

```
5
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

However, in `TensorFlow 2.x` since eager execution is enabled by default
you don't have to make any changes to your code.